# Jasny Twitter Bootstrap implementation give an error on tooltip script

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I have been implementing [Jasny Twitter Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap)  when I call validation for make a popover , an d it is giving me an error about a undefined var.

I am attaching my code in order you could help me with this issue

```
 $('#ReferalAdminAddForm').validate({
                    rules: {
                            'data[Referal][CustomerTypeId]': {
                                    required: true
                            },
                            'data[Referal][town_id]': {
                                    required: true
                            },
                            'data[Referal][nit]': {
                                    required: true,
                                    minlength: 11,
                                    maxlength: 11,
                                    digits: true
                            },
                            'data[Referal][name]': {
                                    required: true,
                                    minlength: 2,
                                    maxlength: 128
                            },
                            'data[Referal][address]': {
                                    required: true
                            },
                            'data[Referal][phone]':{
                                    required:false,
                                    minlength: 6,
                                    maxlength: 16
                            }
                    },
                    highlight: function(element) {
                            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error').popover('toggle');
                    },
                    success: function(element) {
                            element
                            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
                    }
            });
```

Console give this messsage

```
TypeError: b is undefined
.../2,left:c.left-d};break;case"right":g={top:c.top+c.height/2-e/2,left:c.left+c.wi...

bootst....min.js (línea 7)
```

My javascript call are:

```
<script src="/ikarus/j_query/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-transition.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-alert.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-dropdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-scrollspy.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-tab.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-popover.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-button.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-collapse.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ikarus/twitter_bootstrap/js/jasny/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js"></script>
```